# jquery update ul list with xml data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to update a ul in my html with a jQuery function. I would like to read a xml (rss feed) then for each title add it to my ul.

jQuery Function

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(function(){
 jQuery.getFeed({
    url: 'xml/rss-21.xml',
        success: function(feed) { 
       var $ul = $('ul#test').empty();  // the ul where xml will end up....

         $ul.append('<li data-theme="c"><a href="#page1" data-transition="slide">'feed.title'</a></li>');

  });
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="result" 
                <ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="true" id="test">
                    <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading">
                        News
                    </li>
                    <li data-theme="c">
                        <a href="#page1" data-transition="slide">
                            Dolbey and Alpha Systems Announce Strategic Alliance Partnership
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-theme="c">
                        <a href="#page1" data-transition="slide">
                            Dictate Into Your EMR
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li data-theme="c">
                        <a href="http://www.tristateis.com" data-transition="slide">
                            Win a Free Digital Pocket Memo
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                  </div>
```

Comment: I am not sure what is your specific question. Would you please clarify?

Comment: While not exactly sure where you're running into an issue, I'm thinking maybe jQuery's `.parseXML()` function may be of use.

Answer (score 0):

Use this.This will return your RSS as a JSON object to a callback function:

```
function parseRSS(url, callback) {
   $.ajax({
   url: document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=10&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url),
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data) {
   callback(data.responseData.feed);
   }
 });
}
```